# SELECT DISTINCT still showing duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, distinct

Yes, there's a thousand questions about this on SO, but I've been searching for half an hour and I've yet to find a solution.

So, I've a table like this:
[image]

And this is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT rengasID,leveys FROM renkaat ORDER BY leveys ASC
```

And this is the result I get:

[image]

If you get the idea, I'm populating a select field with it, but it still has duplicates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @marcosh: [MySQL usually (and in this case) treats `DISTINCT` like a `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html), thus the `DISTINCT` is applying to "combinations of" `rengasID` and `leveys`.

Comment: That result shows one column. Your query shows two columns!?!?!?

Comment: @Christian Nicely formatted question.(+1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want distinct `levey`s, just choose that field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT leveys
FROM renkaat
ORDER BY leveys ASC
```

The `rengasid` has a different value on each row.

The `distinct` clause applies to all the columns being returned, regardless of parentheses.

EDIT:

If you need the `regasid` in the result, then use `group by`:

```
select leveys, min(regasid) as regasid
from renkaat
group by leveys
order by leveys asc;
```

This gives the first id.  If you need all of them, you can get them in a list using `group_concat()`.  If you need a separate id on each row, well, then you have duplicates.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want for this case. But for the future: What if I need to use rengasID also?

Answer (score 3):

Your `rengasID` is still different in each shown line. The distinct will check a mix of every selected field, so in this case it will search a distinct combination of `rengasID` and `leveys`.

You cannot ask for your ID here, since MySQL has no way of knowing which one you want.

Depending on what you want to do it can be more correct to save your "leveys" (I'm not sure what they are) in a separate table with a unique ID and join it. For filling up your list with all possible leveys, you can just query that new table.
This can be important because using `group by`, you can get random results for id's later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are selecting combination of `rengasID` and `leveys`. And what you are getting as a result is a distinct combination of the two.

To achieve what you are trying, see the answer of @GordonLinoff.

Comment: Oh yes. rengasID happens to be unique, so the query thinks that there is no duplicates.