# Trouble getting distinct results when joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm have a similar issue to [SELECT DISTINCT still showing duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729753/select-distinct-still-showing-duplicates)

I understand now that `DISTINCT` is applied to the whole line, so the result is doing what it should.  I'm trying to return the following rows, but I don't want any duplicate Serial Numbers.  If there are duplicates I would like to just take the last entry.

Here is my query:

```
USE [db1]
SELECT DISTINCT Serial.[Serial Number], Plugin.[Plugin Name] AS [Model], Revision.Revision AS [Firmware Revision], ConnectionType.[Connection Type] As [Connection]
FROM Station
JOIN Plugin ON Station.[Plugin ID] = Plugin.[Plugin ID]
JOIN Serial ON Station.[Serial ID] = Serial.[Serial ID]
JOIN Revision ON Station.[Revision ID] = Revision.[Revision ID]
JOIN Connection ON Station.[Connection ID] = Connection.[Connection ID]
JOIN ConnectionType On Connection.[Connection Type ID] = ConnectionType.[Connection Type ID]
WHERE Station.[MAC Address ID] = (select MAC.[MAC Address ID] from MAC where mac.[MAC Address] = '123456')
ORDER BY Serial.[Serial Number] DESC
```

Here is the result:

[image]

So you can see there are two entries for X12132 because the firmware in that device was updated at somepoint and the DISTINCT was applied to the whole line but unfortunately results in duplicate Serial Numbers.  What should I do to fix this issue?

I've tried doing a `GROUP BY Serial.[Serial Number]` but it gives me the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> Column 'Plugin.Plugin Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

I have a feeling that maybe it has something to do with my joins, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Please let me know if you need more information about the other tables.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is last entry? Last according to what?

Comment: Sorry, I guess that would be good to know.  Yes, by last entry into the database.  Ideally if the firmware gets updated, it will create a new entry, so I'd like to display the device with the latest information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two firmware revisions for `X12132`. You select max firmware revision and group by other columns:

```
SELECT
    Serial.[Serial Number],
    Plugin.[Plugin Name] AS [Model], 
    MAX(Revision.Revision) AS [Firmware Revision], 
    ConnectionType.[Connection Type] As [Connection]
FROM ...
GROUP BY Serial.[Serial Number], Plugin.[Plugin Name] AS [Model], ConnectionType.[Connection Type]
```

Comment: Just be aware this will always get you the highest firmware revision, not necessarily the most recent one. The row_number solution should work in a 2008 or later version.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get what you want with this query is to use `row_number()` in `order by`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES Serial.[Serial Number], Plugin.[Plugin Name] AS [Model], Revision.Revision AS [Firmware Revision], ConnectionType.[Connection Type] As [Connection]
FROM Station
JOIN Plugin ON Station.[Plugin ID] = Plugin.[Plugin ID]
JOIN Serial ON Station.[Serial ID] = Serial.[Serial ID]
JOIN Revision ON Station.[Revision ID] = Revision.[Revision ID]
JOIN Connection ON Station.[Connection ID] = Connection.[Connection ID]
JOIN ConnectionType On Connection.[Connection Type ID] = ConnectionType.[Connection Type ID]
WHERE Station.[MAC Address ID] = (select MAC.[MAC Address ID] from MAC where mac.[MAC Address] = '123456')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Serial.[Serial Number] ORDER BY ? DESC);
```

I don't know how you define "last entry", so `ORDER BY ?` is for the column that defines the ordering.

Comment: I probably didn't do a good job tagging the question.  I'm using MS SQL EXPRESS 2008.  It doesn't seem to know what `ROW_NUBER()` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [db1]
SELECT DISTINCT Serial.[Serial Number], Plugin.[Plugin Name] AS [Model], Revision.Revision AS [Firmware Revision], ConnectionType.[Connection Type] As [Connection]
FROM Station
JOIN Plugin ON Station.[Plugin ID] = Plugin.[Plugin ID]
JOIN Serial ON Station.[Serial ID] = Serial.[Serial ID]
JOIN Revision ON Station.[Revision ID] = Revision.[Revision ID]
JOIN Connection ON Station.[Connection ID] = Connection.[Connection ID]
JOIN ConnectionType On Connection.[Connection Type ID] = ConnectionType.[Connection Type ID]
WHERE Station.[MAC Address ID] = (select MAC.[MAC Address ID] from MAC where mac.[MAC Address] = '123456')
gorup by Serial.[Serial Number],Plugin.[Plugin Name],Revision.Revision, ConnectionType.[Connection Type]
ORDER BY Serial.[Serial Number] DESC
```